# How do I do the emergency turn off Android device with embedded battery?

Tags: malware, power-on

Imagine your device is hacked and you want to turn it off now (because of it is using network in bad manner), but the rootkit blocked all functions.

How do I forcibly turn off the device? I've tried holding the power button and the devide said it will reboot instead of shutting down.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the device, but on Nexus 4, when you hold the power for more than 5 seconds (someone said 15 seconds), it will be forced shutdown. What's your device?

Comment: I've tried on some HTC One (just the nearest device at the moment). I expected it to be device-independent.

Comment: Is this "forced shutdown" really hardwired or it is actually a command to some chip with flashable (i.e. infected) firmware?

Comment: I'm not sure on that, but it works on Nexus 4 running on stock Android (not infected at all). I'll test on other devices when I can access them.

Comment: Devices that have inaccessible batteries "hardwire" the power button to be a force off when held for a time, usually between 5 - 15 seconds. For the HTC One, I have read that putting the device under a bright light source is needed while holding the power. [Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2307252)

Comment: On other device ("Huawei Honor 6") I see this tip in power button menu: `Press and hold power key for 10s or more to forcibly reboot`. OK, maybe force reboot is hardwired, but what about force shutdown?